# String object has no attribute get -error in python code

Tags: python

```
message=""
for action_result_dict in action_results:
            for k,v in action_result_dict.items():
                if k=="message":
                    message=v.get('message',"")
```

I wrote this code to fetch the value of message but its throwing error. String object has no attribute get. Can anyone point out the mistake please ? Thanks

```
[
    {
        "status": "failed",
        "data": [],
        "message": "",
        "parameter": {
            "vault_id": "45aaaecaacdcd45da1071e6c078",
            "force_analysis": true,
            "context": {
                "guid": "54381cf2-99fa-93e3f9ab4b48",
                "artifact_id": 0,
                "parent_action_run": []
            },
            "private": true
        },
        "summary": {}
    },
    {
        "status": "failed",
        "data": [],
        "message": "handle_action exception occurred",
        "parameter": {
            "vault_id": "45aaaecaacdc292ad45da1071e6c078",
            "force_analysis": true,
            "context": {
                "guid": "54381cf",
                "artifact_id": 0,
                "parent_action_run": []
            },
            "private": true
        },
        "summary": {}
    }
]
```

Comment: What is `action_results` ? and What is the error?

Comment: When `k == 'message'`, then `v == ''` or `'handle_action exception occurred'`. It's a string, not a dict. It doesn't have a `get` method. Do you just want `message = v`? Or omit the second loop entirely and just do `action_result_dict.get('message')`?

Comment: message = v would work.

Comment: for action_result_dict in action_results: 
 message = action_result_dict.get('message', '')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings don't have a `get` method. Maybe you want to use the `get` method on the dictionary, `action_result_dict`.

```py
message = None
for action_result_dict in action_results:
    message = action_result_dict.get("message", "")
```

If you want a list of all the messages, perhaps you can do

```py
messages = []
for action_result_dict in action_results:
    messages.append(action_result_dict.get("message", ""))
```

or

```py
messages = [action_result_dict.get("message", "") for action_result_dict in action_results]
```

Comment: No need to initialize `message`

Comment: @AnsFourtyTwo Could be that `action_results` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```
for action_result_dict in action_results:
    message = action_result_dict.get("message", "")
```

Using

```
for k,v in action_result_dict.items():
```

will go throught the dictionary and exctract each item into its key `k` and value `v`, so for example the item `"message": "some message"` within the dictionary will be exctracted to `k = "message"` and `v = "some message"` within the loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Your script should be:

```
message = ''
for action_result_dict in action_results:
    message = action_result_dict.get('message', '')
```

The first loop iterates over the list of dicts you call `action_result_dict`.
The `dict.get()` method already takes care of of the case where the key doesn't exist.